# Lares - Them divide c people into t groups

Tags: c++, if-statement

There is m men, and n women.The boss chooses k people. Them divide m+n-k remain people into t groups, each group exactly 2 men and 1 woman. Find max(t)

**For example:**  
Input 
264936043   821529140   438045170 
Ouput 
132468021

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int n, m, k, res, t;

int main(){
    cin >> n >> m >> k;
    for (int i = max(k-m, 0); i <= n; i++){
        res =  max(res, min((n-i)/2, m-k+i));
    }
    cout << res;
}
```

My code is TLE.

I think the number of men chosen is (n+2*k-2*m)/3 because (n-i) ~ 2*(m-k+i), but it is not correct.

Comment: A loop on the order of 1e8 iterations is obviously going to take too long. Look for an O(1) solution. (what is the most favorable choice of k people you can take away?)

Comment: You can start with (m+n-k)/3 women and (m+n-k)/3*2 men and adjust those numbers downwards if they exceed the number of (wo)men you have available and finally adjust downwards to maintain the ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @dratenik, I used derivative to analyze the function (n-x)/(m-k-x). And this is my accepted code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int n, m, k;

int main(){
    cin >> n >> m >> k;
    if (k >= m+n) cout << 0;
    else if (n/2 <= m-k) cout << n/2;
    else if ((n-k)/2 >= m) cout << m;
    else {
        int t = (n + 2*k - 2*m)/3;
        cout << max(min((n-t)/2, m-k+t), min((n-t-1)/2, m-k+t+1));
    }
}
```